# What is the /bin/[ '[' file in OS X?

Tags: macos, file

[image]

See the screen shot.

There is the '[' file at `/bin`.

What is the '[' file? What does it do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This command is for comparing values, checking file types etc.

Here's a `man` page:

```
NAME
 test, [ -- condition evaluation utility

SYNOPSIS
 test expression
 [ expression ]
```

It's usually used like this:

```
if [ -f /etc/passwd ] 
then
   echo "Yes"
else
   echo "No"  
fi
```

For more info, please read the man page ( `man [` ).

Comment: It's worth noting that the default shell likely has its own builtin version of the [ command that will run instead of the one in /bin. The one in /bin is likely only for compatibility and for particularly minimalist shells.

Comment: Actually, the command, `[` on the filesystem, exists for POSIX compliance (IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'')) and not for compatibility or particularly minimalist shells.

Comment: omg I thought my cat had haxored my mac and renamed a core system file to `[`. but this is used in the `if` command! amaze! Ingenious.